# Double slit experiment - orientation:

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, double-slit-experiment

The bands that result on the "target" screen are vertically aligned - as-are the double slits. Is this due to the slit-orientation or is it a result of the electrons moving through the Earth's gravitational field? And as two follow up questions: Has the same experiment been tried with horizontal or oblique slits and has anyone considered running the same experiment in the microgravity of space?

Comment: The orientation of the pattern is caused by the interference. So the pattern is a function of the distance difference to the two slits, that means the pattern does not change in the direction of the slits, but only perpendicular to the slits.

Comment: They look vertically aligned in figures because it's easier to draw that way. It doesn't make a difference. I've personally done a horizontal double slit experiment and it worked fine.

Comment: Did you do any research into this? The pattern is caused by diffraction/interference and appears equally well for light, why would you think gravity has something to do with it?

Comment: Are you trying to ask why the pattern is not caused by gravity instead? The reason is because if we put a detector next to one of the hole, then the interference disappear. A detector alone can hardly cancel the effect of gravity.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with electrons going through the earths gravitational field. If the slits are vertical then The fringes in the pattern will be vertical and yes the experiment can be done either horizontal or vertical. There are many easy searches online that will explain this.